# How to match two multidimensional arrays according to key and store it in same

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

first array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [size] => L
            [sizecode] => 02
            [style] => SGKT-4
            [color] => NAVY
            [quantity] => 2
            [count] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [size] => M
            [sizecode] => 02
            [style] => SGKT-4
            [color] => NAVY
            [quantity] => 1
            [count] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [size] => XL
            [sizecode] => 02
            [style] => SGKT-4
            [color] => NAVY
            [quantity] => 2
            [count] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [size] => XXL
            [sizecode] => 02
            [style] => SGKT-4
            [color] => NAVY
            [quantity] => 1
            [count] => 1
        )

)
```

second array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-20
            [3] => SGKT-20
            [4] => 02
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-15
            [3] => SGKT-15
            [4] => 02
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 03
            [0] => 03
            [ISIZE] => 3X
            [1] => 3X
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-47BT
            [3] => SGKT-47BT
            [4] => 03
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-95
            [3] => SGKT-95
            [4] => 02
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-16
            [3] => SGKT-16
            [4] => 02
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-48
            [3] => SGKT-48
            [4] => 02
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-71
            [3] => SGKT-71
            [4] => 02
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-19
            [3] => SGKT-19
            [4] => 02
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 03
            [0] => 03
            [ISIZE] => 3X
            [1] => 3X
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-40BT
            [3] => SGKT-40BT
            [4] => 03
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-27
            [3] => SGKT-27
            [4] => 02
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-2
            [3] => SGKT-2
            [4] => 02
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-13
            [3] => SGKT-13
            [4] => 02
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-68
            [3] => SGKT-68
            [4] => 02
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-21
            [3] => SGKT-21
            [4] => 02
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-64
            [3] => SGKT-64
            [4] => 02
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-93
            [3] => SGKT-93
            [4] => 02
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-22
            [3] => SGKT-22
            [4] => 02
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-23
            [3] => SGKT-23
            [4] => 02
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => NDG-VST-001
            [3] => NDG-VST-001
            [4] => 02
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-26
            [3] => SGKT-26
            [4] => 02
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-80
            [3] => SGKT-80
            [4] => 02
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-94
            [3] => SGKT-94
            [4] => 02
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKB-5
            [3] => SGKB-5
            [4] => 02
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => NDG-WJKT-003
            [3] => NDG-WJKT-003
            [4] => 02
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 04
            [0] => 04
            [ISIZE] => 5-
            [1] => 5-
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => CHASTINA
            [3] => CHASTINA
            [4] => 04
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => NDG-WJKT-004
            [3] => NDG-WJKT-004
            [4] => 02
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-67
            [3] => SGKT-67
            [4] => 02
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => NDG-WJKT-010
            [3] => NDG-WJKT-010
            [4] => 02
        )

    [28] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-18
            [3] => SGKT-18
            [4] => 02
        )

    [29] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-82
            [3] => SGKT-82
            [4] => 02
        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-50
            [3] => SGKT-50
            [4] => 02
        )

    [31] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKB-2
            [3] => SGKB-2
            [4] => 02
        )

    [32] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-77
            [3] => SGKT-77
            [4] => 02
        )

    [33] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-85
            [3] => SGKT-85
            [4] => 02
        )

    [34] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-14
            [3] => SGKT-14
            [4] => 02
        )

    [35] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 03
            [0] => 03
            [ISIZE] => 3X
            [1] => 3X
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-42BT
            [3] => SGKT-42BT
            [4] => 03
        )

    [36] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-86
            [3] => SGKT-86
            [4] => 02
        )

    [37] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-10
            [3] => SGKT-10
            [4] => 02
        )

    [38] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-11
            [3] => SGKT-11
            [4] => 02
        )

    [39] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-78
            [3] => SGKT-78
            [4] => 02
        )

    [40] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-12
            [3] => SGKT-12
            [4] => 02
        )

    [41] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 03
            [0] => 03
            [ISIZE] => 3X
            [1] => 3X
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-26BT
            [3] => SGKT-26BT
            [4] => 03
        )

    [42] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-81
            [3] => SGKT-81
            [4] => 02
        )

    [43] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => NDG-WJKT-005
            [3] => NDG-WJKT-005
            [4] => 02
        )

    [44] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKB-3
            [3] => SGKB-3
            [4] => 02
        )

    [45] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-44
            [3] => SGKT-44
            [4] => 02
        )

    [46] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-4
            [3] => SGKT-4
            [4] => 02
        )

    [47] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-40
            [3] => SGKT-40
            [4] => 02
        )

    [48] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => 133-101-15093
            [3] => 133-101-15093
            [4] => 02
        )

    [49] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-87
            [3] => SGKT-87
            [4] => 02
        )

    [50] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-41
            [3] => SGKT-41
            [4] => 02
        )

    [51] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-42
            [3] => SGKT-42
            [4] => 02
        )

    [52] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-9
            [3] => SGKT-9
            [4] => 02
        )

    [53] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-43
            [3] => SGKT-43
            [4] => 02
        )

    [54] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-92
            [3] => SGKT-92
            [4] => 02
        )

    [55] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGJB-10
            [3] => SGJB-10
            [4] => 02
        )

    [56] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-88
            [3] => SGKT-88
            [4] => 02
        )

    [57] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-45
            [3] => SGKT-45
            [4] => 02
        )

    [58] => Array
        (
            [ISCODE] => 02
            [0] => 02
            [ISIZE] => S
            [1] => S
            [SIZESEQNUM] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [ICODE] => SGKT-8
            [3] => SGKT-8
            [4] => 02
        )
)
```

I have to match the size from 1st array and 2nd array and store the sizecode to the second array.

Comment: A ***concise*** example which does not require us to scroll back and forth or print out the question on paper to understand it would be very much appreciated. Also, the expected outcome would help as well. Lastly, what's your issue that's preventing you from solving this yourself?

Comment: it hard to understand me that how to match the key at positions 0 ,1,2... values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no other way than iterate over both arrays to find the matching members and then insert the sizecode from the first into the second.

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
    for ($ii=0; $ii < count($array2); $ii++) {
        if ($array1[$i]['size'] == $array2[$ii]['ISIZE']) {
            $array2[$ii]['sizecode'] = $array1[$i]['sizecode'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If neccessary you could store the found members of array1 in another hasmap that is adressabel directly to decrease the number of iterations.